# Tkinter label overlap

Tags: python, tkinter, label, overlap

for one of my first little projects I coded a fitnesscalculator last evening. Which has 3 functionalities at the start: Calculating the 1RM, BMI and FFMI. I'm running into the problem of overlapping labels when I first calculate the 1RM and then the FFMI. I have already googled and looked for similar threads but I couldn't find an answer to my solutions as my Gui is and its functionalities are based around a combobox. Please excuse the rather messy code, but I have already tried several methods to deal with this problem

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.title("Fitness Calculator")

#dropdown

Options = ["1RM Calculator", "BMI Calculator", "FFMI Calculator"]


#functions


def picker(input):
    global calculate_button
    global bf_box
    global bf_label
    global result_label
    global result2_label
    global result3_label
    calculate_button.destroy()
    result_label.pack_forget()
    result2_label.destroy()
    result3_label.destroy()
    bf_label.destroy()
    bf_box.destroy()
    selected = drop.get() #holt sich wert vom dropdown

    ####################RM CALCULATOR####################
    if selected == Options[0]:
        #labels
        weight_label = Label(root,text="Enter your training weight here: ", padx=10, pady=10)
        weight_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

        reps_label = Label(root,text="Enter your repetitions here: ", padx=10)
        reps_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        def calculate():
            weight = int(weight_box.get())
            reps = int(reps_box.get())
            one_rm = round(weight*(36/(37-reps)), 2)
            #Result
            result_label = Label(root, text="Your 1RM is: " + str(one_rm) + " kg")
            result_label.grid(row=4)
            weight_box.delete(0,END)
            reps_box.delete(0,END)

        #Entryfields

        weight_box = Entry(root)
        weight_box.grid(row=2, column=1)

        reps_box = Entry(root)
        reps_box.grid(row=3, column=1)

        #Calculate button

        calculate_button = Button(root,text="Calculate",command=calculate, width=16 )
        calculate_button.grid(row=4,column=1,pady=10)

    ####################BMI CALC####################
    if selected == Options[1]:
        #LABELS
        weight_label = Label(root,text="Enter your weight in kg here: ", padx=10, pady=10)
        weight_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

        height_label = Label(root,text="Enter your height in cm here: ", padx=10)
        height_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        #ENTRY BOXES
        weight_box = Entry(root)
        weight_box.grid(row=2, column=1)

        height_box = Entry(root)
        height_box.grid(row=3, column=1)

        def calculate():
            weight = float(weight_box.get())
            height = float(height_box.get())/100
            bmi = round(weight/(height**2),0)
            #Result
            result_label = Label(root, text="Your BMI is: " + str(bmi))
            result_label.grid(row=4)
            weight_box.delete(0,END)
            height_box.delete(0,END)
        #Calculate button

        calculate_button = Button(root,text="Calculate",command=calculate, width=16 )
        calculate_button.grid(row=4,column=1,pady=10)


    ####################FFMI####################
    if selected == Options[2]:
        calculate_button.destroy()
      #LABELS
        weight_label = Label(root,text="Enter your weight in kg here: ", padx=10,pady=5)
        weight_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        height_label = Label(root,text="Enter your height in cm here: ", padx=10,pady=5)
        height_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        bf_label = Label(root,text="Enter your estimated bodyfat % here: ", padx=10,pady=5)
        bf_label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
        #ENTRY BOXES
        weight_box = Entry(root)
        weight_box.grid(row=2, column=1)
        height_box = Entry(root)
        height_box.grid(row=3, column=1)
        bf_box = Entry(root)
        bf_box.grid(row=4, column=1)
        def calculate():
            weight = float(weight_box.get())
            height = float(height_box.get())/100
            bf = float(bf_box.get())
            total_bf = weight*(bf)
            lean_weight = weight*(1-(bf/100))
            ffmi = round((lean_weight/height**2),2)
            adjusted_ffmi = ffmi + 6.1 * (1.8 - height)
            #Result
            result_label = Label(root, text="Lean Mass: " + str(lean_weight) + " kg")
            result_label.grid(row=6, sticky=W, padx=5)
            result_label2 = Label(root, text="FFMI: " + str(ffmi))
            result_label2.grid(row=7, sticky=W, padx=5)
            result_label3 = Label(root, text="adjusted-FFMI: " + str(adjusted_ffmi))
            result_label3.grid(row=8,sticky=W, padx=5)
            weight_box.delete(0,END)
            height_box.delete(0,END)
            bf_box.delete(0,END)
        #Calculate button
        calculate_button = Button(root,text="Calculate",command=calculate, width=16 )
        calculate_button.grid(row=5,column=1,pady=10)





calculate_button = Button(root,text="Calculate", width=16 )
calculate_button.grid(row=4,column=1,pady=10)
calculate_button.destroy()



#Dropdownbox

drop = ttk.Combobox(root, value=Options, state="readonly")
drop.current(0)
drop.grid(row=0)
drop.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", picker)

result_label = Label(root,text="test")
result_label.grid(row=4)

result2_label = Label(root,text="")
result2_label.grid(row=4)



result3_label = Label(root,text="")
result3_label.grid(row=4)

bf_label = Label(root)
bf_box = Entry(root)



picker(drop.current(0))
root.mainloop()
```

Here a Screenshot of the problem I'm referencing to:
[image]

Comment: Please narrow down your code to the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `result_label.grid(row=4,sticky='w')`?

Answer (score 1):

You keep creating a new Label with name `result_label` in your calculate methods.
This piles the labels on top of each other, since the `result_label.destroy()` does not remove them from the grid.

Instead of destroying them, keep just one instance (which you already defined global) and then configure them with the new text:

```py
result_label.config(text="Your BMI is: " + str(bmi))
```